How to fix Window is not defined in Angular 17?
I recently upgraded to Angular 17 and the new Verse builder. After running ng build I get:
An unhandled exception occurred: window is not defined
See "/private/var/folders/gv/n0kqs93x29v30b0cfl5tzr140000gn/T/ng-6nQUx1/angular-errors.log" for further details.
The file provides no useful details as it refers to files of the build that do not exist due to the error. I already put all code with window in afterNextRender() logic. Are there any ways to get more information on the error?
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve", 
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"

  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.3.12",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/common": "^17.3.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.3.12",
    "@angular/core": "^17.3.12",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.3.12",
    "@angular/localize": "^17.3.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.3.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.3.12",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^17.3.12",
    "@angular/router": "^17.3.12",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^17.3.12",
    "@angular/ssr": "^17.3.11",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^9.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^42.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core": "^42.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine": "^42.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils": "^42.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-watchdog": "^42.0.0",
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "^6.1.5",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^6.1.5",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^6.1.5",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^6.1.5",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^16.0.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "~12.0.7",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.7",
    "@sentry/angular": "^8.38.0",
    "@sentry/tracing": "^7.114.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/topojson": "^3.2.3",
    "bootstrap": "5.2.3",
    "canvas": "^2.11.2",
    "chart.js": "^4.2.1",
    "chartjs-adapter-date-fns": "^3.0.0",
    "chartjs-chart-geo": "4.1.2",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "localstorage-polyfill": "^1.0.1",
    "ng2-charts": "^5.0.0",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "10.3.4",
    "ngx-colors": "3.5.3",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^17.0.0",
    "ngx-stripe": "^17.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "tslib": "^2.5.0"
  },
  "dependenciesMeta": {
    "@fullcalendar/angular": {
      "injected": true
    }},
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.3.11",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "~17.3.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~17.3.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~17.3.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "~17.3.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~17.3.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~17.3.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~17.3.12",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.6.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.2.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.2.0",
    "browser-sync": "^3.0.0",
    "ckeditor5": "^42.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "3.8",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.1",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^4.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
    "prettier": "^2.8.7",
    "sass": "^1.61.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.2.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "~5.4.5",
    "webpack": "^5.78.0"
  }
}


please share the contents of /private/var/folders/gv/n0kqs93x29v30b0cfl5tzr140000gn/T/ng-6nQUx1/angular-errors.log

[error] ReferenceError: window is not defined
at file:///Users/frontend/.angular/prerender-root/c497c22b-02ce-404a-bfb3-4275248d125e/chunk-VEAIHEON.mjs:2:14081
at file:///Users/frontend/.angular/prerender-root/c497c22b-02ce-404a-bfb3-4275248d125e/chunk-DYTSPR25.mjs:2:1021
at file:///Users//.angular/prerender-root/c497c22b-02ce-404a-bfb3-4275248d125e/chunk-XR5KFSJH.mjs:2:27590
at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:195:25)
at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:337:24)

Unfortunately, the error file is useless as the files it refers to do not exist as the build did not complete

In whatever component you are using window, inject PLATFORM_ID as well:


constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) {}

ngOnInit() {
  if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
    // This code will only run in the browser
    console.log(window);
  }
}



Now you're good to go.

thank you, I know this feature but it should not be necessary to be used if afterNextRender is already implemented

Ideally it should not be. but Angular 16+ is asking for this. There should be an alternative, but I am not aware of it as of now. I'll look into it and keep you posted if I find anything.
